# How test 11ty 404 page?

Tags: http-status-code-404, eleventy

I've build a 404 page for my 11ty project, as shown in the 11ty quick tips:

```
https://www.11ty.dev/docs/quicktips/not-found/
QUICK TIP #006—ADDING A 404 NOT FOUND PAGE TO YOUR STATIC SITE
```

I then added a deliberate link to a non-existing file like so:

`[404 test](/error.html)`

But when I click on this, I just get a console.log error, not the 404.html.  Note that I'm using eleventy's BrowserSync server.

So how can I test the 404 page?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `404/index.html` or `404.html` files in dist folder, do you have a such file in compiled folder?

Also check if you have `404.html`, or `404.njk` file in your src folder.

Comment: Yup I have a 404.html. I think the 11ty browsersynx doesnt use it. I believe it would work on github. maybe live-server or other dev server might work.

Answer (score 0):

Eleventy itself isn't a web server. It runs one locally while you dev, but in production, it's just files. Your web server/host/etc should provide a way to support 404s and you would set it up there.